# How can I simulate a Shift + Click on a Vaadin Button?

Tags: unit-testing, vaadin

I created an application with Vaadin 23 containing buttons (`com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button`) that reacts in differents ways when clicked with and without holding the shift key.

```java
Button button = new Button("Click me", event -> {
  if (event.isShiftKey()) {
    System.out.println("Shift + click");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Click");
  }
});
```

I am now trying to create unit tests for this but I don't know how to simulate the shift key. The Button class only offers a `.click()` method without any parameters.

```java
button.click(); // The "else" part of the event is called
```

Is there a way (without creating a custom Button class) to simulate a shift + click in Vaadin ?

Comment: Here is the documentation of the Button class: https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.2.8/com/vaadin/flow/component/button/Button.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Button.click` is implemented as:

```
public void click() {
        fireEvent(new ClickEvent<>(this, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false,
                false, false));
}
```

`Button.fireEvent` is protected, but you can use `ComponentUtil.fireEvent`:

```
ComponentUtil.fireEvent(
  this,
  new ClickEvent<>(this, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, true, false, false));
  //                                                       ^
  //                                                     shiftKey
```